# How to output 'GETDATE()' string into string column with Liquibase 3.5 for MSSQL with loadData change?

Tags: java, sql-server, liquibase

I have liquibase loadData change:

```
<changeSet author="author" id="13">
        <sql>SET IDENTITY_INSERT M_Conversion ON</sql>
        <loadData tableName="M_Conversion" separator="~" file="data/13-M_Conversion.csv">
            <column name="MconID" type="NUMERIC" />
            <column name="MdbtID" type="NUMERIC" />
            <column name="MlokID" type="NUMERIC" />
            <column name="MconKeyword" type="STRING" />
            <column name="MconExtra" type="STRING" />
        </loadData>
        <sql>SET IDENTITY_INSERT M_Conversion OFF</sql>
        <rollback>
            <sql>SET IDENTITY_INSERTM_Conversion OFF</sql>
        </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

In the 13-M_Conversion.csv file, there is one value that causes problems for MSSQL: `201~2~200~GETDATE()~` the GETDATE() value for column MconKeyword is not quoted as string in the resulting sql

The sql that the liquibase generates for this data is: 
`INSERT INTO [pd].[M_Conversion] ([MconID], [MdbtID], [MlokID], [MconKeyword], [MconExtra]) VALUES (201, 2, 200, GETDATE());` but it should be `(201, 2, 200, 'GETDATE()')`

Problem is, that in method `liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.InsertGenerator#generateValues` for String values there is call to check if the string looks like function call

```
public boolean looksLikeFunctionCall(String value, Database database) {
        return value.startsWith("\"SYSIBM\"") || value.startsWith("to_date(") || value.equalsIgnoreCase(database.getCurrentDateTimeFunction());
    }
```

and for MSSQLDatabase GETDATE() is exactly currentDateTimeFunction

So the question is, how do I get this specific value to be escaped properly with loadData change?

Comment: Did you checkout the attributes you can set on the [`loadData`](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html) function? There is an attribute `quotchar`. Maybe you just need to set this to a single quote char?

Comment: I did look into that, that's just setting for the qote character. Other values for that column are being correctly escaped with default quote character, just GETDATE() is not

Comment: Maybe it helps to know that liquibase uses opencsv under the hood. Maybe you can find a hint in the documentation of opencsv on how to handle your case and then find a way to also use this in liquibase. Sorry, can't help any further...

Comment: thanks for suggestions, in the end i made workaround, added some special characters into source data and then added sql to the loadData change to update that value to be correctly escaped